# ViewPager error(VM wont let us allocate)

Tags: android

I have a problem showing images, im testing my program with Samsung Galaxy Captivate i897, so, the problem is that i want to show images, i'm doing this with a ViewPager, but the ViewPager instantiates always three images (method instantiateItem), before, showing and after images, my images are of 5MB, so the LogCat give me that error

01-29 11:35:48.656: E/dalvikvm-heap(1275): 19660800-byte external allocation too large for this process.
01-29 11:35:48.679: E/GraphicsJNI(1275): VM won't let us allocate 19660800 bytes

I want to know how to avoid to instantiate some of 3 images or how to create an imageView avoiding this problem.

Here is my adapter's code.

public class FullScreenImageViewAdapter extends PagerAdapter
{

```
private final Activity          _activity;
private final ArrayList<String> _imagePaths;

// constructor
public FullScreenImageViewAdapter(Activity activity,
        ArrayList<String> imagePaths)
{
    this._activity = activity;
    this._imagePaths = imagePaths;
}

@Override
public int getCount()
{
    return this._imagePaths.size();
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object)
{
    return view == ((RelativeLayout) object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position)
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) _activity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View viewLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.img_view, container, false);

    TouchImageView imgDisplay = (TouchImageView) viewLayout
            .findViewById(R.id.imgDisplay);

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(_imagePaths.get(position),
            options);

    imgDisplay.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    ((ViewPager) container).addView(viewLayout);

    return viewLayout;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object)
{
    ((ViewPager) container).removeView((RelativeLayout) object);

}
```

}

Comment: what is the image you are using?  png or jpeg?

Comment: Im using JPG phone camera pictures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

compress your image using bitmap options and insample size check this link

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Answer (score 0):

Memory constraints are always hard to solve.

If subsampling is not applicable, you can try loading images on-demand by altering original ImageView (maybe ViewPager or both) to check its visibility and discard uncompressed image data if it is invisible or decoding back if it is visible. For speed you can store compressed images in memory, decoding it on-demand.

Answer (score 0):

Since your images are JPEG, you could use the RGB_565 format as you dont need to display images with an alpha channel (like a png).

```
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
```

this will cause your image to need and use less memory as each pixel is 2 bytes (instead of 4 bytes in ARGB_8888)

More info : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html

Comment: so smoething that took up 19,660,800 bytes will now take about half that (9,830,400)

Comment: I tested this solution with 3MB images and works fine, but what about images of 10MB??

Comment: The amount of memory used by an image depends on inPreferredConfig value used and the number of pixels it contains.  See the more info link.